# How to synchronize multithreading notification for UI update

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a async method that is called when I need to update UI controls content, like this:

```
public async Task UpdateUI(int i)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Enter {0}", i);
    DoSomethingSync(1000);

    Debug.WriteLine("Await {0}", i);
    await GetDataFromServerAsync(5000);

    //Update UI Controls
    Debug.WriteLine("Update {0}", i);
    DoSomethingSync(2000);

    Debug.WriteLine("Exit {0}", i);
}

public void DoSomethingSync(int delay)
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
}

public Task GetDataFromServerAsync(int delay)
{
    return TaskEx.Delay(delay);
}
```

When the data is changed on the server, I get a notification that come in different threads and I have to call a UpdateUI method on the UI thread, like this:

```
public async void OnServerDataChanged(int i)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("WaitOne {0}", i);
    _semaphore.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await UpdateUI(i);
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _scheduler);
    }
    finally 
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
        Debug.WriteLine("Release {0}", i);
    }
}
```

I simulate multithreading notification:

```
public void SimulateMultiThreadingNotification()
{
    TaskEx.Run(() =>
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            TaskEx.Run(() =>
            {
                var id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                OnServerDataChanged(id);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Run:

```
_semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);
_scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
SimulateMultiThreadingNotification();
```

Output:

```
Enter 11
Await 11
Release 11
Enter 12
Await 12
Release 12
Enter 6
Await 6
Release 6
Update 11
Exit 11
Update 12
Exit 12
Update 6
Exit 6
```

How to synchronize so that the method executed sequentially like this:

```
Enter 11
Await 11
Update 11
Exit 11
Release 11
Enter 12
Await 12
Update 12
Exit 12
Release 12
Enter 6
Await 6
Update 6
Exit 6
Release 6
```

Advance thanx!

Edit:
I found solution:

```
public void OnServerDataChanged(int i)
{
    _semaphore.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await UpdateUI(i);
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _scheduler);
        tcs.Task.Wait();
    }
    finally 
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
        Debug.WriteLine("Release {0}", i);
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Solution by  Yuval Itzchakov:

```
public void OnServerDataChanged(int i)
{
    _semaphore.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await UpdateUI(i);
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _scheduler).Unwrap().Wait();
    }
    finally 
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
        Debug.WriteLine("Release {0}", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you check the `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext` at your different stages of functions? To find out where the Synchronization to the WPF/WF dispatcher is lost?

Comment: @Nitram, UpdateUI should always executed on the UI thread. Synchronization is lost due to the method GetDataFromServerAsync call inside UpdateUI method, then the semaphore is released and a re-entry into UpdateUI. How to prevent the release of the semaphore until the end of the execution UpdateUI method?

Comment: That is strange. `await` should always capture and restore the synchronization context.

Comment: I found solution! Need to use TaskCompletionSource in OnServerDataChanged!

Comment: O.o Wha? Could you answer your own question to show how you solved it? I don't think I understand how you got it working with a `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: @Nitram, show my edit question!

Comment: That works? That means that something is wrong with the `_scheduler`. If it would actually schedule the tasks in the WPF/WF scheduler this code would lead to a deadlock.

Comment: It works perfectly! I checked!

Comment: That is because your `_scheduler` doesn't schedule the tasks in one thread as the one of a GUI Framework would do. Instead it uses the `ThreadPool` to schedule tasks. This code will not work inside a UI Framework.

Comment: @Nitam, _scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(); You can test my Solution and make sure that it works!

Comment: What is the current synchronization context at this point? This method always works, but if here is no current synchronization context you will just get a `TaskScheduler` that uses the `ThreadPool`

Comment: @Nitam, _scheduler variable initialize one way in main window constructor

Comment: Could you write down the type of what `Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` returns? At the point where you fetch the `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: @Nitam, I do not understand what you want to prove to me, give me a email and I'll send you my project and you do all the necessary tests

Comment: Hey I am not trying to prove anything. I think you have a issue in there that is shadowed by your testing environment. If you are good with the way it works right now, so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the fact `Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't "handle" `async Task` returning lambdas properly, since they generate a `Task<Task>`, where you actually `await` on the outter `Task`, not the inner one.

You can use `SemaphoreSlim` instead of a `Semaphore`, it has a [`WaitAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462740(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can asynchronously wait on.

Calling `Unwrap()` will solve your problem:

```
private SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
public async Task ServerDataChangedAsync(int i)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("WaitAsync {0}", i);
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await UpdateUI(i);
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _scheduler).Unwrap();
    }
    finally 
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
        Debug.WriteLine("Release {0}", i);
    }
}
```

Also, don't do `async void`, that's for event handlers. Do `async Task` instead.